# Making a button responsive with px

Tags: html, css

I have 3 boxes on my website. On the bottom of each there is a button that fills exactly the size of that box. I did this by using width 322 px, which works perfect on 13" and above. However, it is a complete mess below that. How do you ensure something is responsive -- and especially in a case like this where it has to fill exactly the full width of a box. Is px not the way to go about it?

Comment: Use width: 100% instead of a fixed number of pixels.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Use Media Query to change layout according to device width:

see the example for your reference ,
Open the example in full page and resize is to see the changes.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <style>
      button{
        width:400px;
        height:50px;
        
      }
      
  @media screen and (max-width:980px) {
      button{
        width:100%;
      }

}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
  </body>

</html>
```